# Azure SignalR Connection String for Azure Function App ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-function-app, azure-signalr

I would just like to ask if there is an ARM template function that can get the Azure SignalR connection string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use listKeys() function:

```
listkeys(resourceId('Microsoft.SignalRService/SignalR', 'resourceName'), 2018-10-01)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#list

Answer (score 2):

I had to modify the above by adding ".primaryConnectionString" to the above like this:

```
listkeys(resourceId('Microsoft.SignalRService/SignalR', 'resourceName'), '2023-02-01').primaryConnectionString
```

Note the template version is a different date.